# Solve $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}^\top = \mathbf{B}$ for a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $\mathbf{R}$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are diagonal matrices with positive entries. Can I find a rotation matrix that satisfies the following equality:

$$ 
\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}^\top = \mathbf{B}
$$

My observations

- The $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix can be written in terms of the angle $\theta$. If so, there will be only one parameter that we need to estimate but there are four equations to satisfy.
- $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{R}^\top$ appears to be the eigenvalue decomposition of a square symmetric matrix. If so, unless $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$ can we find a solution, which is again gives $\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I}$ .

Comment: Multiply the equation by $R$ on the right. Then you get a system of equations linear in $R$, which you can solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base change will leave eigenvalues invariant. Thus $A$ and $B$ must have the same eigenvalues (thus the same elements in the diagonal, just maybe in a different order).

But then we can assume that $R$ switches coordinates in some way so that each $e_i$ maps into $\pm e_j$ so that $A_{i,i}=B_{j,j}$ (more correctly, it has to map eigenspaces to eigenspaces, but in case that all eigenvalues are distinct this is equivalent and if not we find a $R$ that satisfies the former condition).

Such a matrix is either a rotation or a reflection, determined by the determinant. Now how do be determine this? Suppose the diagonal entries are all distinct. Then there is a unique permutation $\pi$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ so that $A_{i,i}=B_{\pi(i),\pi(i)}$.

$R$ can be given by $e_i=e_{\pi(i)}$ and the determinant of $R=R_\pi$ is given by the parity of $\pi$, so if $\pi$ consists of an even number of transpositions it is a rotation, else it is a reflection.

If it is a rotation, we’re done. If it isn’t, we can replace $R$ by $RS_{i}$ where $S_i$ is the identity with $-1$ in the $i$-th position. This does not change the result, but changes the determinant.

Now if two diagonal values are the same there are multiple possible such permutations, as if $A_{i,i}=B_{j,j}$ then we can simply multiply the permutation with the transposition $(i,j)$ to receive a new valid permutation. Note that this changes the parity of the permutation, thus it would be possible to get an even permutation $\pi$ and thus a rotation $R_\pi$ that solves your equation.

EDIT: For the eigenspaces part: Let $x$ be in the eigenspace of $B$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $R^Tx = y+r$ with $y$ in the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$ and $r$ othogonal to the eigenspace.

Then $AR^Tx = \lambda y + r'=\lambda y + \lambda r + (r'-\lambda r)$ for some $r'=Ar$.
But then
$$ \lambda x = Bx = RAR^Tx = \lambda A(y+r) + A(r'-\lambda r)=\lambda x + A(r'-\lambda r)$$
This implies $\lambda r = r' = Ar$. But as $r$ is orthogonal to the $\lambda$-eigenspace this implies $r=0$.

Comment: "If it isn’t, we can replace $R$ by $RS_i$ where $S_i$ is the identity with −1 in the $i$-th position": what does this mean? Are you saying that if $R$ is a reflection matrix then we should multiply $R$ by $S_i$ to get the rotation matrix?

Comment: @shani Yes. $S_i$ is the map that maps $e_i$ to $-e_i$ and $e_j$ to $e_j$ for $j\neq i$. Note that if $D$ is diagonal, then $S_iDS_i^T = S_iDS_i = D$. Thus
$$ RS_iA(RS_i)^T = RS_iAS_i^TR^T = RAR^T$$
or in fact also
$$ S_iRA(S_iR)^T = S_i RAR^T S_i^T = RAR^T$$
Thus we can simply choose $RS_i$ or $S_iR$ instead of $R$. And $S_i$ has determinant $-1$, so $RS_i$ is a rotation iff $R$ is a reflection.

Comment: @shani And of course it does not matter *which* coordinate we flip, just any will do. You can even flip multiple ones, as long as it is an odd number.